# How to convert String (which is of type Map[String, String]) to regular Map in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I am getting a Map[String, String] as a String in the calling method. I am trying to convert the incoming String  to Scala Map.
I tried
Below is the snippet.

```
val mapIm = Map("Aaple" -> 30,  
                 "Orange" -> 20,  
                 "Banana" -> 50).toString
// Output: mapIm: String = Map(Aaple -> 30, Orange -> 20, Banana -> 50)
// Desired op: mapIm: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Aaple -> 30, Orange -> 20, Banana -> 50)
```

Comment: Why converting a **Map** to a _HUMAN_ readable **String** in the first place? Especially if you want to process it again by a _MACHINE_.

Comment: Yes I understand. But while passing nested parameter while calling one databricks notebook in another, then converts Map parameter to String. So i was trying to find a way so that I can convert back to Map again.

Comment: I haven't used databricks notebooks. But I am pretty sure there should be a better way to passing data from one into another than relaying in strings. And if not, then use an appropriate format like **csv**, **json** or **xml** instead of relaying in `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the code that's delivering a `String` where it should be a `Map`.

Until then...

```
val mapRE = "(\\w+) -> (\\d+)".r

mapRE.findAllMatchIn(mapIm)
     .map(m => m.group(1) -> m.group(2).toInt)
     .toMap
//res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(Aaple -> 30, Orange -> 20, Banana -> 50)
```